# TeamCity build is triggered using branch with no pending changes

Tags: build, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have a build configuration that is triggered on a schedule (nightly).
It is marked to **only execute when there are pending changes**.

The VCS root that is attached to this build configuration is set to monitor a bunch of different git branches:
[image]

Notice that the default branch is '*integration*', which has no changes, but other branches **do have changes**. I would expect the build to trigger using the branch with the pending changes, and not using the default branch, which has nothing new on it.

Why is the build triggered on the wrong branch then? did i configure something wrong ?

Comment: all triggers work s only on the default branch.

Answer (score 3):

Could you try this?

Triggers -> Schedule Trigger -> Additional Options -> Show Advanced options
[image]

Add the branch specification: 
[image]

Comment: yes, this solves the issue, but why isn't it on by default ?

Comment: I don't know :)